# Test automation in Linux: Simulate login to display manager (kdm)

Tags: automated-testing, linux

Assume I want to simulate a login in the display manager to automate a test case. More or less this would mean a tool simulating keystrokes I guess. Is there anything out there?

Options I'm aware of, but I'm *not* asking for:

- Disable the login completely using automatic login or password-less login

Using xnee you can do something similar, but sadly does not work fully:

1. Lock your screen
2. Run cnee (xnee) on a virtual console CTRL + ALT + F1 to record mouse movements and key strokes: `cnee --record --keyboard --mouse --display :0 --out-file login.xnl`. This will record mouse movements and key strokes from display :0.
3. Switching back to X console
4. Click into the password field, enter password and press RETURN
5. Switch back to virtual console to stop recording with CTRL + C
6. Run cnee to replay the captured events `cnee --replay --display :0.0 --file login.xnl`
7. Immediately switch back to the X console (otherwise the commands will not be replayed there)
   You're logged in now.

What finally rendered the solution useless is that you have to switch to the X console, what would need to be automated, too.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to test the display manager and not automate the login on a physical machine. (By the way I think [KDM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KDE_Display_Manager) is dropped with the release of KDE Plasma 5 and now uses [SDDM](https://github.com/sddm/sddm/) instead since a couple of years.)

One possible way is to use VNC:

- Start a [x11vnc](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/) server, which starts the display manager you want to test
- Connect with a VNC testing framework (for example [T-Plan Robot](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tplanrobot/))
- Run script to sendkeys and verify login

Alternatively check out [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) to drive a VM (for example with [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)).

- Start a VM with the display manager visible
- Start a Sikuli script on the host computer

Siluki might also work against a physical machine when using [xrdp](http://www.xrdp.org/).

Comment: It's about automating the login on a physical machine as part of a test precondition and it could be part of a test ensuring certain logins exist and work as expected.

Comment: Now I think about it shouldn't matter to much. You should be able to run both solutions from a machine against that machine, but I think its easier if you test against a virtualmachine. This would make it scale better to.

Comment: I'll have a look at it. I also thought about using X forwarding.

Comment: With X Forwarding you still have to find a way to drive, maybe http://xautomation.sourceforge.net/ works in this case, but I have never tried it.

Comment: Expecco is available to me -- it should be able to do this (although I have to evaluate).

I also found the cnee parameter --display which did the trick. I'll add another answer describing what I did.

Comment: Updated the question instead of adding a new answer, as what I thought is a solution is none. :-/